# Problem with the function f7Init in shinyMobile package

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

at the end of last year I made a small application with the shinyMobile package, in my code I included this segment:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- f7Page(
    title = "shinyMobile",
    init = f7Init(
                  skin = "auto",
                  theme = "light",
                  color = 'blue',
                  filled = TRUE,
                  hideNavOnPageScroll = FALSE,
                  hideTabsOnPageScroll = FALSE
                 ),
                 …
```

It was working great, but now with the new package modifications I changed it like this:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- f7Page(
    title = "shinyMobile",
    options = list(
                   skin = "auto",
                   theme = "light",
                   color = 'blue',
                   filled = TRUE,
                   navbar = list(
                                 hideNavOnPageScroll = FALSE,
                                 hideTabsOnPageScroll = FALSE
                                 )
                   ),
…
```

And now I don't have my upper and lower bars, what could I do.Thank you in advance for his kind help.